# Why is Yahoo! Slurp requesting /1338.aspx?

Tags: yahoo, slurp

```
Ip: 67.195.112.247 
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp/3.0; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp) 

System.Web.HttpException: The file '/1338.aspx' does not exist.
```

---

> IP    :   67.195.112.247
>   Host  :   b3091104.crawl.yahoo.net
>   Country:  United States

Comment: Because it's one better than 1337?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Slurp had indexed an example log file I was using for an old log analyzer project at

> https://bitbucket.org/mrshrinkray/projects/src/fa550b822a52/Statmagic/Statmagic.Testapp/ExampleLogs/ex071110.log
>
> 2007-11-10 19:44:35 W3SVC421807 WEB150 216.177.83.9 GET /1338.aspx - 80 - 66.249.70.48 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html)

The log file had a record of Googlebot requesting the URL, I have no idea how did Googlebot got the none-existence url but it s hows Slurp likes to mimic Googlebot.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching on the open web for "http://yoururl/1138.aspx" ,  someone may have created this link and yahoo is trying to follow it.

Comment: Is it 1138?  If so, it might be George Lucas related.